# Remove marker based on location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to remove a marker on my map based on it's address but it's not working for some reason. It must be something obvious that i'm not seeing. It's not going into the    if(m==locationsall[i][0]) in the deleteMarker method even though i've ensured that m and locationsall[i][0] are identical.

```
    //alert(tmp);
    //alert(locationsall[0][0]);
```

Adding to map code:

```
$('#map').show();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value +",  " + document.getElementById("city").value;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            locationsall[counter] = new Array();
            locationsall[counter][0] = address;
            locationsall[counter][1] = lat;
            locationsall[counter][2] = lng;
            var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < locationsall.length; i++) {  
            locationsall[i][3] = marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locationsall[i][1], locationsall[i][2]),
            map: map
            });
            //markersArray.push(marker);
    }
    counter++;
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Code that retrieves the address from a textbox and formats it to '1 main street, city'

```
    var tmp = locations.splice(locations.indexOf(location), 1);
    deleteMarker(tmp);
```

Delete marker code:

```
function deleteMarker(m){
for (i = 0; i < locationsall.length; i++) { 
     if(m==locationsall[i][0]){
     alert(locationsall[i][0]); 
 alert(locationsall[i][3]);
      locationsall[i][3].setMap(null);
     } 
  }
}
```

Comment: A jsfiddle that demosntrates the problem (or a live link) would be useful.

Comment: You cannot use a global variable, like 'counter', inside an asynchronous function.

Comment: That part of the code works. Adding markers is not an issue. It's the removal of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had an extra space when I compared m and locationsall[i][0];

The code works perfectly now.